# onScroll getting called after Activity has left screen

Tags: android, listview

I was originally using a ListActivity.  It was managed with a CursorAdapter.

I overrode the onScroll method to update a UI element based on what is visible to the user as they scroll through the ListView.  My onScroll method accesses the Adapter's Cursor to check some data about the first visible item.

I've decided to place another ListView on the screen, so I've changed it to an Activity (instead of a ListActivity), given the ListView an +id and created a member variable for it in the Activity.  I changed all references to getListView() to that variable.

This is working fine except for one thing:  If you click an item in the list it launches a new Activity.  After this new Activity shows up on the screen, the onScroll method for the previous Activity gets called.  It crashes the application.

It's strange because the first two lines in my overrode onScroll make sure the Cursor is not null, it is open, has a count > 0, and moves to the visible position.  These two lines work fine.  However, when I attempt to pull data from it, the application crashes with the following error:

```
01-12 13:22:47.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526): android.database.StaleDataException: Access closed cursor
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:217)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:135)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at com.myapp.app.activity.ActivityPrepare$4.onScroll(ActivityPrepare.java:160)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.widget.AbsListView.invokeOnItemScrollListener(AbsListView.java:656)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1429)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1113)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:996)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-12 13:22:47.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(526):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm supposing there is some sort of race condition, but why is onScroll getting called when the Activity isn't even on the screen?

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: That sounds odd.. did you look at the activity lifecycle?  Is this being called after onPause?

Comment: Yes. It is being called after onPause and onStop

Comment: According to Google's documentation, stopping an Activity that is managing a Cursor (ie: you called startManagingCursor(cursor)) will deactivate the Cursor.  If Cursor objects had an isActivated() method, I could probably get around this, but it does not appear that they do.

Comment: I've gotten around this crash by making sure the visibleItemCount parameter of the onScroll method is > 0, but I still don't like that onScroll is being called after onPause() and onStop()